# Log Likelihood function for Machine Learning Algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, log-likelihood

I am implementing logistic regression in Python and am at the point where I am writing code for maximum likelihood estimation for a parameter vector according to this formula:

[image]

I have implemented it in the following manner:

`-np.sum(np.log(1 + np.exp(-1*(y*x.dot(w.T)))))`

In a function where `w` is the weight vector, `x` is the feature matrix, and `y` is the label vector. I am not obtaining the classification I expect based on test data and suspect it has something to do with the way I've implemented this log-likelihood equation. I run this function in scipy.minimize.optimize where the additional paramters are the initial weight estimates (all initialized to zero) and args = (x,y). In terminal, I get the following errors:

`RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp; return -np.sum(np.log(1 + np.exp(-1*(y*x.dot(w.T)))))`

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract df = fun(x) - f0`

It is a simple binary classification task. Can someone provide some hints as to why this may be happening and how I can address it in the most efficient manner possible?

**EDIT**: A colleague of mine suggested that this same operation could be done using `logsumexp()` in that it is more numerically stable, but I'm not sure how this is possible so the equation requires a sum of logs but `logsumexp()` is a log of sums. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to post an example of the inputs that are causing the same issue. You can't pose the entire data likely, so you need to identify a small sub-sample of the data that causes the same issue. See proving a MRE here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when `-1*(y*x.dot(w.T))))` is too large, funtion `exp` will overflow.
I test on my x64 machine and find when the parameter for `exp` is larger than `750`, `exp` will overflow:

```
>>> np.exp(750)
inf
>>>
```

Thus I suggest a normalization applyed on weight `w` and input `x`.